# Endless scroll and Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, infinite-scroll, will-paginate, endlessscroll

Google analytics is not tracking new page loads with endless scroll and will_paginate gem.

Here is my GA snippet:

```
<script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)  {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new   Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-60189417-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/articles/cross_country']);


  </script>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why do you have a _gaq call in your code? Do you create a tracker object based on Classic GA?

Comment: Some old thread suggested this as a solution to this problem. Since posting this I've learned this won't work. Any other ideas?